# Multiple query to columns indexed in MySql

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, query

I am trying to make a table with server-side page, so it can also apply filters for each of the columns in my table. This is its structure:

```
+----------------+
|    products    |
|----------------|
| id       int   |
| title    string|
| date     date  |
| category string| 
+----------------+
```

so it occurred to me to create a composite index for the columns that I want to filter:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON products(c2,c3,c4);
```

The problem, as the documentation says, is that the query optimizer cannot use the index to perform searches if the columns do not form a prefix to the left of the index. then I could not make a `WHERE` condition to a specific column if it is not in the correct order of the index, which is a problem for me, since my query could include one or more conditions in any order, according to the user's need for example:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE title = ""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE date = ""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = ""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE title = "" AND date = ""
SELECT * FROM products WHERE title = "" AND date = "" AND category = ""
```

So an index of multiple columns is not the best option for my case, so I thought to add an individual id to each of my columns, is this a good practice or is there another way to address this problem?

Comment: There is **NO** fields with the names `c2`,`c3`,`c4` in the table structure.

Comment: *This is its structure* This is pornography, not structure. Post `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` output. FULL output.

Comment: It is a reference to columns 2, 3, 4

Comment: Does ANY fields combination in WHERE clause is possible? or 5 shown combinations only? And - specify the amount of records in the table and the amount of distinct values in each separate field (approximate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This index will take care of 3 of your queries:

```
INDEX(title, date,  -- in either order
      category)     -- last
```

Then you will need two more indexes to handle the other two queries.  Assuming you use the order above, then these could be the other two.

```
INDEX(category)
INDEX(date)
```

If you have a dozen columns and users can filter on virtually any combination of them, then all you can do is guess at what is best.  Some general rules:

- don't make more than a dozen indexes
- use about 3 columns in each index
- be sure to start some of them with the most commonly used filters

But also, ...

- If the filtering is on a range (eg, price range), it should be last in the index.
- Don't listen to people who talk about cardinality when arguing for a particular order of columns in a composite index.
- If `title` is too big to be indexed, then leave it out of all indexes.  Do not use "prefix indexing" like `title(20)`.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql